# Decrypting TS Files Individually

Tags: encryption, aes

Could someone help me fix this code?
This is actually fully working but, this code will automatically merged the output files
I want to decrypt each file only and not automatically merged

Here's the code:

```
Sub decrypt()
    Try
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Application.DoEvents()

        If txtFileName.Text = "" Then
            txtFileName.Text = "DecryptedFile"
        Else

        End If

        Dim folder As String = txtSource.Text
        Dim encryptionKey As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(txtKey.Text)
        Dim outputFile As String = (txtFilePath.Text + "\" + txtFileName.Text + ".ts")

        Using outputFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create)

            Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.ts")

            For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1
                Dim encryptionIV As Byte() = New Byte(15) {}
                Using inputFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(files(i), FileMode.Open)

                    Using aes = New AesManaged With {
                        .Key = encryptionKey,
                        .IV = encryptionIV,
                        .Mode = CipherMode.CBC
                    }

                        Using encryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor()

                            Using cryptoStream = New CryptoStream(inputFileStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

                                cryptoStream.CopyTo(outputFileStream)


                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Next
        End Using
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If you wrote this code then you should be able to easily make the changes you want.

Comment: No I just found here also but in C# Code so I translated it to vb.net

I can't figure out how it can decrypt each file only